# What is the pythonic way to alternate between two functions in a loop

Tags: python

It seems like a simple question to me, but a search yielded nothing useful.

I have code like below:

```
    for key, v in enumerate(ranges):

        ### Used to switch between voltage steps
        second_iter = 0

        for step in v:

            ### Set voltage sources to differential voltages
            if second_iter == 0:
                self.tf.institf.dcm.vsource1(step)
                second_iter = 1
            elif second_iter == 1:
                self.tf.institf.dcm.vsource2(step)

            self.measure_something()
```

v is a 2 element list. ranges is a list of v's. I want to cycle through each v, but use the second element in a different function each time.

Is there a pythonic way to write the code above?

Edit: To clarify, I want to do some separate code afterwards which measures something. So I can't set both functions at the same time.

Comment: I assume you meant to add `second_iter = 0` in there?

Comment: Yes, because I want the first iteration to be 'second_iter = 0', then the second time around to be 'second_iter = 1'. Then the loop ends because v is only two elements. I am wondering if there is a more pythonic way to achieve this.

Comment: maybe you should highlight that v only has two elements... most of the answers are assuming that it is larger and that you want to alternate between the two functions.

Answer (score 7):

Your code is very little intuitive... Is this not enough to do that, without abusing loops?

```
vsource1 = self.tf.institf.dcm.vsource1
vsource2 = self.tf.institf.dcm.vsource2

for key, (v1, v2) in enumerate(ranges):

    vsource1(v1)
    # Do some other stuff

    vsource2(v2)
    # Do some other stuff
```

Alternatively, if the "stuff" is the same you can indeed use a loop like this to avoid repeating yourself:

```
vsource1 = self.tf.institf.dcm.vsource1
vsource2 = self.tf.institf.dcm.vsource2

funcs = (vsource1, vsource2)

for key, steps in enumerate(ranges):
    for func, step in zip(funcs, steps):
        func(step)
        # Do some other stuff
```

Comment: Ok this answer is very general and allows to call more than two functions, not bad.

Comment: I suppose if `#Do some other stuff` is identical in both situations, then we would want to use something like `cycle` to choose which function to use, rather than repeat the other code.

Comment: @AndrewGuy Indeed, thank you. Yet, I do not think `cycle` is usefull here as there is only two functions. The title of this question is misleading

Comment: Probably not needed to call `cycle` inside the loop - you can just build it once outside.

Comment: @Delgan Ah, yep, I missed that there was only ever two values to iterate over. Your edit seems to me to be the most 'Pythonic' way.

Comment: Why is the title misleading?

Comment: @Gambles Because you do not need to actually "alternate between two functions", you just need to execute two different functions with different argument.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
for key, v in enumerate(range(0, 100)):
     [fun_call1() if key % 2 else fun_call2()]
```

Comment: I added a modulo operation. Why would this be bad?

Comment: And why is this bad?

Comment: Modulo 2 is not in the least costly. You simply check one bit and you get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This reduces the amount of code and reduces the need of conditional evaluation to 1 for each iteration.

```
for key, v in enumerate(ranges):

    if key % 2 == 0:
        self.tf.institf.dcm.vsource1(v[0])
    else:
        self.tf.institf.dcm.vsource2(v[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If v is a 2 element list, I'd write it like this:

```
for key, (step1, step2) in enumerate(ranges):
    self.tf.institf.dcm.vsource1(step1)
    self.measure_something()

    self.tf.institf.dcm.vsource2(step2)
    self.measure_something()
```

Pythonic doesn't always mean to use the most advanced functions to generate the shortest code. Because of the fixed length of v in your example, I'd say that the solution above is the easiest to read and therefore pythonic.

Comment: Sorry I should clarify, I can't set both functions at the same time. They must be set individually in each iteration. Edited my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Simple indexing into second list can help avoid loop and second_iter variable

```
for key, v in enumerate(ranges):
    self.tf.institf.dcm.vsource1(v[0])
    self.measure_something()

    self.tf.institf.dcm.vsource2(v[1])
    self.measure_something()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `itertools.cycle` and `zip`:

```
from itertools import cycle

vsources = [self.tf.institf.dcm.vsource1, self.tf.institf.dcm.vsource2]


for key, v in enumerate(ranges):
    for (step, vsource) in zip(v, cycle(vsources)):
        ### Set voltage sources to differential voltages
        vsource(step)
```

**Edit:** I realise now that there is only two values in each `v`, so no need to use `cycle`.  Delgan's answer seems to cover this well, so I'll just leave this as-is, and defer to his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly pythonic, but you can use the remainder operator to switch between the two functions:

```
funcs = [func1, func2]

for i, voltage in enumerate(ranges):
    for step in voltage:
        func = funcs[i % 2]
        func(step)
```

**OR**

This one's not DRY, but *probably* makes better use of the cache by grouping all calls to each function. Slice `ranges` into the two arrays you need, then call the function on the subarray:

```
range1 = ranges[0::2]
range2 = ranges[1::2]

for step in range1: func1(step)
for step in range2: func2(step)
```

Inlining the slices:

```
for step in ranges[0::2]: func1(step)
for step in ranges[1::2]: func2(step)
```